# Vitis: Store 16 byte variable into 4 32-bit registers

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, zynq

I have a const unsigned char input, 16 byte. And I need to store it into 4 32-bit registers. Vitis allows to store 32 bit variable to 32 bit register using Xil_Out32. But I do not know how can I separate a 16 byte input to 4 pieces.

```
#define MY_REGISTER  XPAR_AES_ENCDEC_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR /*Get the register address*/
#define MY_REGISTER_1  MY_REGISTER + 0
#define MY_REGISTER_2  MY_REGISTER + 4
#define MY_REGISTER_3  MY_REGISTER + 8
#define MY_REGISTER_4  MY_REGISTER + 12

void key_init(const unsigned char key[]);
     Xil_Out32(MY_REGISTER, /*4 byte key*/);
```

This is the key I will receive. Input testbench from VHDL code:

key <= x"00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff";

And I want to put it into 4 register. I already got the register base address:
00112233 to MY_REGISTER_1,
44556677 to MY_REGISTER_2,
8899aabb to MY_REGISTER_3,
ccddeeff to MY_REGISTER_4.

Comment: How is your 16-byte input represented, as an array of what type, as a structure of what? Please provide some more context. You should also make clear how you like to distribute the bytes to the registers.

Comment: I think the type is char type since it is const unsigned char. I think it is an char type array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the pointer to the bytes into a pointer to 32-bit values, and use this to read the values for the registers.

```c
void key_init(const unsigned char key[]) {
    const u32* pointer = (const u32*)key;
    Xil_Out32(MY_REGISTER_1, pointer[0]);
    Xil_Out32(MY_REGISTER_2, pointer[1]);
    Xil_Out32(MY_REGISTER_3, pointer[2]);
    Xil_Out32(MY_REGISTER_4, pointer[3]);
}
```

***Notes:***

An array given as a function parameter is converted to a pointer.

Accessing `pointer[index]` is equivalent to `*(pointer + index)`.

Please consider endianness, you might need to use `Xil_Out32BE()` or `Xil_Out32LE()` or change the sequence of indexes to `pointer`.

Your byte array needs to be aligned on a `u32` boundary, if your processor needs this. Anyway, if the byte address is not convertible to a `u32` pointer because of alignment, this is Undefined Behavior. It *might* work, but only for your specific target.

Comment: Appreciate! I will try it